# Genymotion - Goldfish causing problems, any way to rollback?

Tags: android, android-emulator, kernel, genymotion

All Genymotion devices / images are now running `goldfish`, however some apps (Instagram for example) are blocking all requests from devices on `goldfish`.

I was wondering if there is a way to rollback or load up an image using `hammerhead` for example, which works fine.

Worth to mention; requests are blocked server side (they return a 400 error), this is due to having `goldfish` in the `user-agent` header.

proof:

goldfish -
[image]

dankmemes -
[image]

Obviously I have the option to setup a proxy server to deal with a `user-agent` header, but it would save me a lot of trouble if there was a way to rollback to another kernel.

Comment: Hi, did you solved the problem ? I am facing almost the same problem, the difference is that i am using the official android avd emulator on ubuntu.

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI Unfortunately I didn't, you would need to change build.prop I think.